# Bazel coverage in golang project is always empty

Tags: go, code-coverage, bazel

I'm on a macOS M2 using `bazel 6.1.1` and `go version go1.20.2 darwin/amd64`.

I'm following the Bazel coverage documentation here: https://bazel.build/configure/coverage.

And I'm using this sample repository here to see the coverage report for a golang project: https://github.com/HappyCerberus/bazel-golang-minimal-example (blog article [here](https://medium.com/@simontoth/golang-with-bazel-2b5310d4ce48)).

```
$ bazel coverage --combined_report=lcov //... --nocache_test_results
WARNING: Running Bazel server needs to be killed, because the startup options are different.
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Using default value for --instrumentation_filter: "^//".
INFO: Override the above default with --instrumentation_filter
INFO: Analyzed 3 targets (70 packages loaded, 7951 targets configured).
INFO: Found 2 targets and 1 test target...
INFO: LCOV coverage report is located at /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ilop/485731b719b452a8b57e8b381b13b359/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat
 and execpath is bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat
INFO: Elapsed time: 5.826s, Critical Path: 0.45s
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal, 1 darwin-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
//:greeter_test                                                          PASSED in 0.1s
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ilop/485731b719b452a8b57e8b381b13b359/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/testlogs/greeter_test/coverage.dat

Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
There were tests whose specified size is too big. Use the --test_verbose_timeout_warnings command line option to see which ones these are.
```

Then I check `$(bazel info output_path)/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat` file, but it is always empty. What am I doing wrong?

I recall reading about Bazel's limitation about broken baseline coverage files, so is this the same problem?

Others have reported similar issues with different setups, but the same problem:

- https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/7719
- https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/15254
- https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/16515

Comment: I have GoLand and the Bazel Plugin installed. If I run bazel coverage via the context menu I get the coverage statistics - no idea how this is done internally by GoLand and Bazel Plugin, but it works

Comment: @Vertexwahn Thanks for the tip, I'll give that a try. Did you use the sample repo I posted above or some other project?

Comment: Some other project